# When I create a class, I receive "illegal start of type" error in "try-catch" block

Tags: java, try-catch

```
class address
{

String address;
String newaddr = address.trim();
final int ziplength =4;
    String input;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String temp = in.next();
    String zipcode = input.substring(input.length()-ziplength);

    try **//illegal start type error**
    {
        Integer.parseInt(zipcode);
        System.out.println("PO is: "+zipcode);    
    }
    catch( Exception e) **//illegal start type error**
    {
        System.err.println("Last 4 chars are not a number.");
    }
}
```

This code segment extract the last four characters from a string, and see if they are post code.

I have commented the point reporting "illegal start type error" in NetBeans.

I wonder, if I cannot use try-catch when creating a class? Or, do this class miss something?

I tried searching stackoverflow. But I am still confusing. Here are some links.

[Java illegal start of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653625/java-illegal-start-of-type)

[Java error: illegal start of expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562950/java-error-illegal-start-of-expression)

[java: Why does the program give "illegal start of type" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448768/why-does-the-program-give-illegal-start-of-type-error)

Comment: missing key word public??

Comment: Uh, in fact I miss a block putting my statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does **not** allow you to simply put statements in the body of a class. You always need an enclosing "block" around those statements.

In other words: the easiest way to a first working example would be to add a main method to your class and to move your code in there. Meaning a method with signature `public static void main(String[] args)`

Beside that: don't "wait" until several errors come together. Start with an empty class. Enter one new construct in there. Save; run the compiler. Go for the next "element" that you need.

For a beginner, your strategy (lets write 10, 20 lines of code; and then lets hope it works) will not work at all. You are wasting your time (and ours) by doing it like that. You see, this is so basic stuff that you should **not** turn to other people to explain them to you. You should start small and figure all these things yourself. Because that is the essence of learning programming.

Comment: I am shocked when seeing this. Yes. what I do so is to simply understand how to do something in a simple and clear test. Could you tell me what is better for a beginner?

Comment: The point is: the basic structure of java programs is explained in many many tutorials out there. But you prefer to not start reading there, but to put up a question here. Most likely, you will run into a similar problem in a few minutes. Whats next then; writing up the next question? As there are already other problems in your code; or do you intend to then solve this problems yourself? What I am saying is: you need a certain "base knowledge" that enables you to write and run programs written in java. Do you really expect us to explain these base things to you? One by one?

Comment: Oh. Clear. I understand. And I know I cannot JUST ask questions. Although I want to say your word is a little bit hard to me, I must say thank you for your words.

Comment: Thank you very much for reacting like this! I agree that my words are a bit harsh; but I have seen too many folks that act exactly like I described: they come to stackoverflow and somehow think this site can work as "detour"; allowing them to skip the essential "learning" part. So I really appreciate that you give your feedback; and that my words didn't discourage you completely.

Comment: Yes, although I am in fact weaker than you can see. ;) I have seen such folks before I come here. Therefore I say I cannot JUST ask questions. Tell you what? I am confusing about how to use getter, but now I try to study by myself instead of Simply posting question here. Thank you for your praise. I know I have too much to do on programming learning. :)

Comment: I think it takes careful balancing. I am not saying that you can't write such questions; it might "just" be that you receive similar feedback again (and not only by myself); or more downvotes than helpful answers. And at least for getters/setters, this here should be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036970/how-do-getters-and-setters-work answering whatever is unclear about them.

Comment: In fact this one is the one I am studying. Down vote? When I double check, I understand. May I delete this question? I don't know. But yes, I believe everyone should try to ask such silly questions, wasting not only their time, but also answer's time. It's sad that I didn't understand this before posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
class address
{
    String address;
    String newaddr = address.trim();
    final int ziplength =4;
    String input;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String temp = in.next();
    String zipcode = input.substring(input.length()-ziplength);
public address() //this is the only thing I add, but it eliminate "illegal start type error"
        {
    try 
    {
        Integer.parseInt(zipcode);
        System.out.println("PO is: "+zipcode);    
    }
    catch( Exception e) 
    {
        System.err.println("Last 4 chars are not a number.");
    }
        }
}
```

Special thank you for @Jägermeister . He gives me valuable hint.

Since I am a beginner, I am thinking a better way to improve my skills. I will try more.